# ASP classic msmtp sending email

Tags: asp-classic

I am using ASP classic to send email by using msmtp. However, none of the following works

```
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /C echo ""hello world"" | c:\path\to\msmtp.exe recipient@mail.com" , 0, true
objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /C ""echo hello world"" | ""c:\path\to\msmtp.exe"" ""recipient@mail.com""" , 0, true
objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /C ""echo hello world | c:\path\to\msmtp.exe recipient@mail.com""" , 0, true
objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /C echo hello world | c:\path\to\msmtp.exe recipient@mail.com" , 0, true
```

Comment: Have a look at [How do I execute a DOS command / batch file / exe from ASP?](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-execute-a-dos-command/batch-file/exe-from-asp.html). First thing that springs to mind is does the account your IIS site is running in (IUSR_something probably) have permission to execute the file in the path `c:\path\to\msmtp.exe`?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use CDO?

Comment: @Lankymart, I have read your article. But there is no any runtime error output. I have tried even I give the permission to "Everyone" to execute the file, including the accessing the folder, but it still does not work.

Comment: @Lankymart, thank you. Your suggestion about the permission is correct. That is because the msmtp.exe will use a configuration file. Yet the configuration cannot be accessed by the IUSR_somebody. So, problem solved once the file permission is configured. Thanks.

Comment: @Allen Glad to help, post your solution as an answer that way you can accept it and remove the question from the unanswered list. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @John, there are a lot of reasons that I don't use CDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by giving permission to IUSR to access the configuration file used by msmtp. Then the syntax works fine.

```
objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /C echo ""hello world"" | c:\path\to\msmtp.exe recipient@mail.com" , 0, true
```